# Can "%.70s" in scanf format string lead to unexpected behaviour?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I just came across this confusing piece of code in a meant-to-be-vulnerable C program:

```
sscanf(user_input, "FOO;%.70s", buf);
```

Is this format string valid? I tried actually parsing something with it (i.e. read something into `buf`, but it didn't work:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char buf[100];
    memset(buf, 0x41, sizeof buf);

    // output: "FOO;asdasd\n"
    printf("FOO;%.70s\n", "asdasd"); 

    sscanf("FOO;asdasd", "FOO;%.70s", buf);

    // output: 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
    for (int i = 0; i< 10; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
    puts("");
}
```

My main question would be if I can actually read data into `buf` using it, maybe even more than 70 bytes?
However, if this is undefined behaviour, can it somehow lead to memory corruption directly when compiled and run on user input with a modern GCC?

**CLARIFICATION:** I know that `"FOO;%70s"` would work. That is not at all the question though. I cannot modify this program. It's a setuid binary and I want to exploit it as part of a wargame to escalate privileges on a Linux machine. So I need to understand completely what it does, and especially whether I can read something in to `buf` via this `sscanf` statement.

Comment: Suspect `"FOO;%.70s", buf);` is UB in `sscanf()`.  Would expect something like `"FOO;%70s", buf);`  (no `.`)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh As I cannot find in the C spec,usage of `.` as part of a `*scanf()` specifier.

Comment: @chux ah, my bad. Was thinking of printf. Right

Comment: I tested your code and if you change %.70s to %70s it works fine I'm not sure if you need the dot there

Comment: @Pooya sure, but that's not the question :)

Comment: CVers please be aware there are two parts to this question and OP is aware the first part is a typo.

Comment: @NiklasB. To guard against future typo votes, might I recommend a new title? Something like "Will "." in scanf lead to memory corruption with a modern GCC?"

Comment: @NiklasB. In my opinion more descriptive titles are better; something like "%.70s" is pretty localized; how many other people are likely to have that string in their code vs using a "." or worrying about memory corruption? :-) But, it's your call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `'.'` is not defined in C as part of a `*scanf()` specifier.  So the result is UB.

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined C11 "7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function" §7.21.6.2 13

---

"If this is undefined behaviour, can it somehow lead to memory corruption when compiled and run with a modern GCC?"
Perhaps.  I have found nothing in GCC that specifies what happens with a `'.'`.  Although unexpected specifiers might not cause great harm based on experience, there is no reason to count on that.

---

[OP later addition]

"So I need to understand completely what it does, and especially whether I can read something in to buf via this sscanf statement."

The presence of the `'.'` renders the specifier invalid.  Therefore the `70` in `"%.70s"` is of dubious value in limiting input.  Thus the code *may* act like `"%s"` which is no better that `gets()` and can lead to excessive input and buffer overruns.  Example `"FOO;asdasd"` was modified to change its null character to something else.

Comment: _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."_ We have a close-vote reason specifically meant to be used for "Typo" questions. Please use it, instead of answering.

Comment: @Cerbrus This question is *not* about how to do it correctly. It's about whether doing it this way is harmful or simply does not work. Please read the question carefully...

Comment: @Cerbrus Although it could be considered a typo, the presence of a similar format used in code in a `printf()` bears discussion.  Many `printf()` formats have nearly the same syntax and format re-use is not uncommon. - even if incorrect in this case.  Thus I do not see this as a typo.

Comment: Hm, I see. Tyler's comment on the question cleared it up for me.

Comment: I underestimated how ambiguous my original question was. Thanks for adding in a response to my edit as well.

Comment: "Example "FOO;asdasd" was modified to change its null character to something else." What do you mean by that? I cleared the buffer with 0x41 bytes if that's what you're referring to

Comment: @Niklas B.  This code sample offers no opportunity for user input, so I am assuming an _evil_ user may selectively altered the executable code.  Modifying the string literal  `"FOO;asdasd"` was subject of my comment.  So rather than ending with a null character and limiting the data written into `buf` to  `"FOO;asdasd"`, code may save far more than 100 `char` into `buf`.  What is there to stop it?

Comment: @chux To clarify, the first argument to sscanf *is* the user input. By the way I solved the challenge by now, the bug had nothing do to with the sscanf in question